# Initialise reference variable as a class member

Tags: c++, class, reference

I am trying to convert a function from a camera SDK I am using to a class, so I can call the different parts of the function separately (initialisation, capture image, clean up). A problem I am having is that some variables in the function are defined as:

```
type& var = type::init();
```

This doesn't work when I do:

```
class myClass
{
private:
type& var;
};
```

I've tried to change:

```
type& var;
```

To:

```
type* var;
```

And that worked fine when I had everything in a single function, but when I try to break it up into separate functions in a class, the code compiles but doesn't run. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my code?

EDIT:
The code is from Basler's SDK, the original code is:

```
Pylon::CTlFactory& TlFactory = Pylon::CTlFactory::GetInstance();
```

In the header file:

```
Pylon::CTlFactory *TlFactory;
```

And the cpp file:

```
TlFactory = &Pylon::CTlFactory::GetInstance();
```

As mentioned, when all the code is in a single function, it compiles and runs fine, it's only when I break it up into class functions that I have problems...

Comment: If you have run-time issues after changing from reference to a pointer, you need to show us more code. Like, how `var` is initialized ?

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, more code has been added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

References are not assignable. When you have a reference as a class member object, you need to initialize it in the constructor. For that, you use the constructor initialization list:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass( type& some_var )
      : var( some_var )
    {}

private:
    type& var;
};
```

Comment: The way the code is written (not mine) at the moment, it gets a bit too complex if I used the constructor initilisation list, e.g. if I have two variables, the second one is dependent on the first one. This is why I tried to change the references to pointers.

Comment: @chocobo_ff: dependencies are fine, members of the class are guaranteed to be initialized in the order they apear in the class definition (not the initializer list).

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer, took a while but think I have solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of K-ballo, note this (useful, IMO) feature of C++ scoping rules:
you can expose the very same name as formal parameter in the constructor. This allows handy code cut & paste, avoiding the need to dream of 'use once' names.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass( type& var )
      : var( var )
    {}

private:
    type& var;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass() : var(Pylon::CTlFactory::GetInstance())
    {
        // rest of init logic
    }
private:
    Pylon::CTlFactory& var;
};
```

Comment: Problem with doing that is, I have something like `IPylonDevice &Camera = *TlFactory.CreateDevice(devices[ 0 ]);`, followed by `IStreamGrabber &StreamGrabber = *Camera.GetStreamGrabber(0);` which is dependent on `Camera`... what do I do about those in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Just do the same thing. That should work fine, as long as you have defined `Camera` before `StreamGrabber` in the class declaration.